# explain this php code please

Tags: php

I know that `$arr = array()` creates a new array called `$arr`, but what is `"somearray"`?

```
<?php
     $arr = array("somearray" => array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42));
     echo $arr["somearray"][6];    
     echo $arr["somearray"][13];   
     echo $arr["somearray"]["a"];  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The "somearray" is a key.  See the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) entry for arrays for detailed explanation of the PHP vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-dimensional array. 'Somearray' is the key for first row in this two-dimensional array. Imagine you want to create 2x2 martix.

```
m = [a b]
    [c d]
```

So that when you get those values

```
m[0][0] => 'a'
m[0][1] => 'b'
m[1][0] => 'c'
m[1][1] => 'd'
```

This can be written using PHP in many ways:

Way #1:

```
$m = array();
$m[0][0] = 'a';
$m[0][1] = 'b';
$m[1][0] = 'c';
$m[1][1] = 'd';
```

Way #2:

```
$m = array(
 0 => array( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b'),
 1 => array( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'd')
);
```

Way #3:

```
$m = array();
$m[0] = array( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b');
$m[1] = array( 0 => 'c', 1 => 'd');
```

If you type:

```
print_r($m);
```

You will get same result for the three ways.

Answer (score 0):

somarray is an associative name. This way you can access this "somearray" by typing $arr["somearray"]

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

In typicaly programming, you can only use a number, but in PHP you can use a name, and that's call associative.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's called an associative array. `"sommarray"` is the key in the array `$arr` for the value `array(6 => 5, 13 => 9, "a" => 42)`. `$arr` is a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

`somearray` is the key in the array, its value is an array. In this array it has other key/value pairs. To get or set the values you can reference them like what you've included by first referencing the first key then the second key.

`echo $arr["somearray"][6]`

`$arr["somearray"][6] = 4`

Answer (score 0):

`"somearray"` is a key. More specifically, an associative index.

The code is employing the [array function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) (rather than syntax) to create an array. Using array syntax, the code could have been written:

```
$arr['somearray'][6]   = 5;    
$arr['somearray'][13]  = 9;   
$arr['somearray']['a'] = 22;
```

The end result is the same.